# Xcode and navigating autocomplete dropdown

Tags: swift, xcode, autocomplete, xcode8

I'm just making my first steps in iOS development and one thing baffles me very much about Xcode.

Why up/down arrow keys don't work for navigating Swift autocomplete suggestions?
Instead, the autocomplete menu disappears immediately. Is it a bug?

Xcode 8.3.2 (8E2002)

Comment: Seems to be a an XCode bug, i am on XCode 8.3.1 and it works. Also could you check if you have the up and down arrow keys mapped to some other action.

Comment: Up and down arrows are mapped to "Move up/down (selection)". If I remove those mappings, normal caret navigation breaks.